# Не отображается содержимое формы во время выполнения продолжительной функции

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть функция, которая может выполняться длительное время.
Прикрутил форму. Но она полностью не отрисовывается.
Хорошего примера с `Timer` не нашел.
Возможно знатоки подскажут как решить?

```
// блокирую основную форму
this->Enabled = false; 
// вызываю форму с текстом "Подождите..." 
F3=gcnew Form3();
F3->Show(this);
// без этой строчки после закрытия формы основная прячется
this->F3->Closed += gcnew EventHandler(this,&Form1::form2_Closed);
// выполнение "тяжелой" функции
grid = gridObj.getResolve(grid);
// закрываю форму "Подождите..."
this->F3->Close();
// разблокировал основную форму
this->Enabled = true;
```

В результате `Label` не отрисовывается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли без таймера что-то сделать?
Подскажите пример решение для *Visual C++* c таймером.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще второй поток тут нужен  , если я правильно понял, что Вы хотите.
Нужно будет функцию в отдельном потоке выполнять

Вот рандом ссылка на уроки по многопоточности
http://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/potoki-v-si-sharp.html

Забыл ещё один момент:попробуй окно обновить(перед тяжелой функцией) WinApi способом.  InvlidateRect() + UpdateWindow ()

Comment: Спасибо! С InvlidateRect() + UpdateWindow () не понял как прикрутить. А на счет потоков, то мне кажеться должен быть вариант попроще, как вариант через таймер.

Comment: нашел подобное для UpdateWindow () - Update();

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить "F3->Update();" Решение:

```
// блокирую основную форму
this->Enabled = false; 
// вызываю форму с текстом "Подождите..." 
F3=gcnew Form3();
F3->Show(this);
F3->Update(); // !!!!!!!!!!!
// без этой строчки после закрытия формы основная прячется
this->F3->Closed += gcnew EventHandler(this,&Form1::form2_Closed);
// выполнение "тяжелой" функции
grid = gridObj.getResolve(grid);
// закрываю форму "Подождите..."
this->F3->Close();
// разблокировал основную форму
this->Enabled = true;
```